# How to bind radio button value to the Model

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, binding, radio-group, radiobuttonlist

`enter code here`I am making a quiz of multiple choices, how can I bind the user selected choice through a group of radio buttons, console.log(selectedOp) gives a value of undifined, please someOne give me a solution 
    home.html

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group radio-group [(ngModel)] = "selectedOp">
        <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label >Q{{name?.num }}: {{name?.detail}}</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{name?.optionA}}</ion-label>
         <ion-radio slot="start" name= "option" [value]="A" ></ion-radio>
         </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{name?.optionB}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" name= "option" [value]="B"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{name?.optionC}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" name= "option" [value]="C"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{name?.optionD}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" name= "option" [value]="D"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </ion-list>

home.ts 

export class HomePage {
  [x: string]: any;
  question: any;
  state: any = 0;
  score: any = 0;
  selectedOp: any;
  name: any;

  constructor() {
    this.timeOut();
    this.question = DB.questions;
    this.name = this.question[0];
    console.log(this.selectedOp);

  }`
```

> enter code here

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is actually correct, but the you log the value of the selectedOp in constructor is wrong because obviously on initialization of the component the value of the selectedOp is undefined and you log it.

One way you can check the value of the radio-group is to add an event handler on the element something like

```
// .html
<ion-radio-group radio-group (ionChange)="onOpChange($event)" [(ngModel)] = "selectedOp">...</ion-radio-group>

// .ts
onOpChange($event) {
    console.log($event); // logs the event obj
    console.log($event.target.value); // logs the selected value

}
```